# WPF: Animate derived control content on mouse hover?

Tags: c#, wpf, animation

I have a control derived from Button:

```
public class ToolButton : Button
{
    static ToolButton() {}

    public ImageSource ImageSource
    {
        get { return (ImageSource)GetValue(ImageSourceProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ImageSourceProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ImageSourceProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ImageSource", typeof(ImageSource), typeof(ToolButton), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));
}
```

and a style for it:

```
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type wordplay:ToolButton}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type wordplay:ToolButton}">
                    <StackPanel Height="Auto" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="4">
                        <Image Source="{TemplateBinding ImageSource}" Stretch="UniformToFill" />
                        <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Content}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Foreground="{DynamicResource TaskButtonTextBrush}" FontWeight="Bold"  Margin="5,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="12" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Now I need to animate TextBlock width on mouse hover, so when user hovers the button with just image the text will be shown. And if user takes mouse pointer away the text is hidden. I want this to be set in style so it will work for any ToolButton. The problem is - I don't know the resulting size of a ToolButton, so I can't animate width. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Why do you need to animate width? If all you need to make it hidden then why not play with Visibility?

Comment: When the button is not hovered, there's just an image: [Not hovered](http://grab.by/kQpm); [Hovered](http://grab.by/kQpI)